# data from a json object not inserting into mysql in php foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert the results from a json array into MySQL using

```
foreach ($feed->items as $item) {
  $query = "insert into data(id,url,keyword)values ($item->id, $item->url,$item->kind)";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  echo $result;
}
```

I have confirmed the database details are OK and the $items are correct.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am fairly new to PHP so any help is appreciated.

Comment: how ur json string look like and for string values need to enclose them with `''` in insert.

Comment: Where is end your foreach loop?

Comment: Executing SQL queries in homogeneous loop is almost always a bad idea - like in your case. Didn't anyone told you that `INSERT` can be used to insert multiple rows?

Comment: Just yourself 1 thing: How should PHP know, if this  `values ($item->id, ...` is (part) of a variable, or a string you want to represent? If you have 2 variables, `$item->i` and `$item->id`, how should PHP know the difference??

Comment: @DanFromGermany of course you are right. It can be deducted even from SO code coloring...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the values in the SQL:

```
$query = "insert into data(id,url,keyword)values ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($item->id) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($item->url) . "' , '". mysql_real_escape_string($item->kind) . "')";
```

1. this adds quotation marks `'` around the variables so that the SQL can be parsed at all
2. This prevents [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/578588).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your variabels in your query :

```
$query = "insert into data(id,url,keyword)values ('{$item->id}', '{$item->url}', '{$item->kind}')";
```

Comment: SQL injection vulnerable - I can break your website/webapp in 1 minute.

Comment: I know. I'm simply answering his question. That's what this website is for you know?